# SQLServer jdbc batch execute performance

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am using following pattern to execute jdbc batch on the SQLServer 2008 R2. The batch execute is simple MERGE statement on one table with proper indexes as per MERGE join clause.

```
batchSize = 50;
for(.....){
...
...
...

    //add to batch
    ps.addBatch();
    if (count >= batchSize) {
        result = ps.executeBatch();
        count = 0;
    }
}
if (count > 0) {
    result = ps.executeBatch();
    count = 0;
}
```

I have very large data pumping into for-loop. What i have observed is initially execution of batch of size 50 takes approx. 150 msec, and then it increases exponentially to 2.5 miunutes when reaches to counts of 400k records!

Is there some sqlserver specific tunning needed?

Comment: Have you tried varying your batch size?

Comment: Yes, still same behavior...

Comment: Adding a half a million records in 2.5 minutes doesn't sound that bad. Have you seen better performance elsewhere?

Comment: what i am hard time to find is that why each batch execution time is exponential when connection is auto-commit!

Comment: An interesting task could be to insert a Thread.timeout and pause a timer to see if the database just needs the extra time to index all of those records against each other. Or, turn off auto commit and see if committing manually changes anything, you'd have to use a transaction.

Comment: Well, i tried that option as well, it takes 4 hours!!

Comment: Can you post the SQL for the merge statement? Could be an inefficiency in the query that becomes more noticeable as more data is inserted. Another possibility are resource bottlenecks such as IO. You could monitor wait stats as the query is running as well as disk perf.

Comment: I changed to simple INSERT improvement is not a major.

Comment: Question: What is ideal performance for inserting 400k rows into single table? i am able to achieve only 3 hr time with JDBC4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to **@30 minutes** time for Insert data volume of 400k!!! I have to do following:

- Change MERGE to DELETE/INSERT (If kept MERGE it takes 1.5 hrs)
- Increase batch size to 1k
- Commit after every batch execute
- Call ps.clearBatch() after batch execute

That is it... :)